# How to fix:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent _id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access  the route `127.0.0.1:8000/product/2`
which is my 
product detail page, I set the relationship within my category model so i'm not sure what the issue is since the `parent_id` actually exists in the categories table

I set the relationship within my category model so i'm not sure what the issue is ?

the function responsible for the this task in my `ProductsController.php` is as follows:

```
<?php
    public function product($id=null){
        //show 404 page if page is disabled
        $productsCount = Product::where(['id'=>$id, 'status'=>1])->count();
        if($productsCount==0){
            abort(404);
        }
        //Get product Details
        $productDetails = Product::with('attributes')->where('id',$id)- 
          >first();
        $productDetails = json_decode(json_encode($productDetails));

        $relatedProducts = Product::where('id','!=',$id)- 
         >where(['category_id'=>$productDetails->category_id])->get();

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent _id'=>0])- 
        >get();

        $total_stock = ProductsAttribute::where('product_id', $id)- 
        >sum('stock');

        return view('front.PdtDetail')->with(compact('productDetails', 
        'relatedProducts', 'categories'));

    }
?>
```

then Category.php

```
<?php 
        public function categories(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');

    } .    
?>
```

I expect to be directed to the product detail page but instead the above error came up.

Comment: change this line `$categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent _id'=>0])->get();` into this `$categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id', 0])->get();`

Comment: Jeez thanks i've spent like 2 hours non stop and couldn't see that space between parent and _id which was the cause thanks .

Comment: `$categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent _id'=>0])->get();` remove the space between `['parent _id'=>0]`